# Checking which function is true and false

Tags: php, validation, csv

**Sorry for the terrible headline, let me try to explain below.**

I have written a bunch of small functions that either returns true or false.

```
validateName()
validateEmail()
validateAddr()
validateBirtd()
validateUsername()
```

Now I am looping through a lot of data imported with a CSV file, and checkin which data is valid or not (returns true or false).

I do it this way:

```
if (validateName($data[0]) == true AND validateEmail($data[1]) == true AND validateAddr($data[3]) == true AND validateBirtd($data[5]) == true AND validateUsername($data[6])==true) {
 // create array to import etc etc
}else{
 // create other array with data who failed validation, to show user later..etc etc
}
```

My question is - is there a more clever way to do this? Would it be possible to create a list of for each failed validation ? Say 3 entrys has fails the validateEmail() function, and 10 both fails validateEmail and validateName().

Would there be a way for me to sort this so I can tell the user "these entrys failed email validation" and "these entrys failed Name and email validation".

I thought about validating one field at a time, but this way I would have duplicates if one entry has more than one validation error.

Would be cool if there was some kind of logic that I don't know of where I could do this

Comment: you can just combine all functions to one wrapping function, pass in the $data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Iterators` to get CSV content and filter at the same time. you can also add different callback to each CSV index

**Example**

```
$csv = new CSVFilter(new CSVIterator("log.txt"));
$csv->addFilter(0, "validateName"); //<------------ Means validate Index at 0
$csv->addFilter(1, "validateEmail");
$csv->addFilter(2, "validateAddr");
$csv->addFilter(3, "validateBirtd");
$csv->addFilter(4, "validateName");
$csv->addFilter(5, "validateUsername");

foreach ( $csv as $data ) {
    var_dump($data);
}

//To get Errors 
var_dump($csv->getErrors());
```

**CSV Filter**

```
class CSVFilter extends FilterIterator {
    protected $filter = array();
    protected $errors = array();

    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator) {
        parent::__construct($iterator);
    }

    public function addFilter($index, Callable $callable) {
        $this->filter[$index] = $callable;
        $this->errors[$callable] = 0;
    }

    public function getErrors() {
        return $this->errors;
    }

    public function accept() {
        $line = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        $x = true;
        foreach ($this->filter  as $key => $var ) {
            if (isset($line[$key])) {
                $func = $this->filter[$key];
                $func($var) or $this->errors[$func] ++ and $x = false;
            }
        }
        return $x;
    }
}
```

**CSVIterator**

```
class CSVIterator implements \Iterator {
    protected $fileHandle;
    protected $line;
    protected $i;

    public function __construct($fileName) {
        if (! $this->fileHandle = fopen($fileName, 'r')) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Couldn\'t open file "' . $fileName . '"');
        }
    }

    public function rewind() {
        fseek($this->fileHandle, 0);
        $this->line = fgetcsv($this->fileHandle);
        $this->i = 0;
    }

    public function valid() {
        return false !== $this->line;
    }

    public function current() {
        return array_map("trim", $this->line);
    }

    public function key() {
        return $this->i;
    }

    public function next() {
        if (false !== $this->line) {
            $this->line = fgetcsv($this->fileHandle);
            $this->i ++;
        }
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        fclose($this->fileHandle);
    }
}
```

**Simple Random Functions**

```
function validateName($var) {
    return mt_rand(0, 5);
}

function validateEmail($var) {
    return mt_rand(0, 5);
}

function validateAddr($var) {
    return mt_rand(0, 5);
}

function validateBirtd($var) {
    return mt_rand(0, 5);
}

function validateUsername($var) {
    return mt_rand(0, 5);
}
```

Comment: +1 for another very robust solution. Thank you for helping steer the newbies in a better direction.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I will try out both solutions! OOP is the way to go (just need more practice!) :)

Comment: @Bolli note that this would both `Read` , `validate` and `Filter` `CSV` content at the same time ...

Answer (score 5):

You could create a function.

```
function validate($data) {
  $errors = array();
  $fields = array('Name', 'Email', 'Addr', 'Birtd', 'UserName');
  foreach ($fields as $i => $field) {
    $func = 'validate'.$field;
    if (!$func($data[$i])) {
      $errors[] = $field;
    }
  }
  return $errors;
}

$errors = validate($data);
if (empty($errors)) {
  // create array to import etc etc
} else {
  // errors
  echo 'There are errors with ' . implode(',', $errors);
}
```

Comment: That looks very much what I am looking for! Thanks alot I will try it out :)

Comment: Didn't know you could do that with functions

Comment: +1 for simplicity and because of how little time that takes a coder to write ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you something a little more encapsulated, you can try this.  It allows you to write different validators for each CSV file you may be validating. Additionally, you could write methods in either class that would allow you to perform additional tasks on each row.  I just find it a little cleaner and easier to maintain than having a bunch of globally-named functions.

Note: I'm obviously using some pretty basic validator examples and exceptions.  The idea here is that I'm providing a layout for you to follow; you can customize any specific behaviors however you'd like.

#### usage

```
$c = new UserCsvValidator('user_data.csv');

try {
    $c->validate();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

#### implementation; parent class

```
<?php

class CsvValidator {

    private $filename;
    private $fh;
    protected $fields = array();

    public function validate__construct($filename, ) {

        $this->filename = $filename;

        // open file
        if ( ($this->fh = fopen($this->filename, 'r')) === false) {
            throw new Exception("could not open file: {$this->filename}");
        }
    }

    public function validate() {
        while( ($row=fgetcsv($this->fh)) !== false) {

            // create hash
            if ( ($hash = array_combine($this->fields, $row)) === false) {
                throw new Exception("invalid row" . print_r($row, true));
            }

            // validate
            foreach ($hash as $field => $value) {

                // determine method call
                $method = "validate_{$field}";
                if (!method_exists($this, $method)) {
                    throw new Exception("validation method not defined: {$method}");
                }

                // validate the field
                if (call_user_func(array($this, $method), $value) === false) {
                    throw new Exception("invalid value for {$field}: {$value}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### implementation; subclass

```
<?php

class UserCsvValidator extends CsvValidator {

    protected $fields = array('name', 'email', 'address', 'birth_date', 'username');

    // example functions for each field
    protected function validate_name($value) {
        return !empty($value);
    }

    protected function validate_email($value) {
        return strpos($value, '@') !== false;
    }

    protected function validate_address($value) {
        return !empty($value);
    }

    protected function validate_birth_date($value) {
        return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value)) == $value;
    }

    protected function validate_username($value) {
        return !empty($value);
    }
}
```