# Read data from csv file into cakephp array

Tags: php, cakephp, fgetcsv

I am developing an application in cakephp where I want to import the csv file and save the data into database.

So I need some help in reading csv file into an array after which I will do some validation and insert data into database.

I have searched a lot but could not find the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13558050/1226894

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use CakePHP's already-existing csv datasource in a custom model.

It is here - https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/master/Model/Datasource/CsvSource.php

See [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html) for how to use them.

Then you can just use your normal `$model->find()` operations on it! Simple!

Answer (score 1):

Try with `fgetcsv()`, here's the doc: [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)